# CentOS/RHEL: How to disconnect established connection and prevent subsequent connections until reboot?

Tags: networking, centos, iptables, centos-7

I'm trying to test a system that uses multiple interconnected hosts, with one of the hosts randomly selected as the leader and the others being members. The members connect to the leader on a specific port, e.g, `12345`. Here is sample `netstat` output showing the members (`*.102`, `*.103` connected to the leader `*.101`):

```
[user@leader ~]$ sudo netstat -peanut | grep :12345
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:12345      0.0.0.0:*                LISTEN      0          23181      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:12345      192.168.1.102:42518      ESTABLISHED 0          44598      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:12345      192.168.1.103:33532      ESTABLISHED 0          48602      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:12345      192.168.1.101:34544      ESTABLISHED 0          26196      -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:34544      192.168.1.101:12345      ESTABLISHED 0          24756      -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.1.101:12345      0.0.0.0:*                            0          24755      -
```

When a member is disconnected from the leader, it immediately tries to re-establish the connection. I attempted to kill the established connection via `sudo tcpkill -i eth1 -9 host 192.168.1.103` but the connection is immediately re-established. I also tried to block the the local port first using `iptables` with `sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DROP` before running `tcpkill`, but I get the same issue.

I can't quite tell if this is an issue with `iptables` itself or if my command is invalid. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iptables command looks fine at first glance. Is iptables running and in charge of firewalling on the host? IIRC, CentOS ships with firewalld on by default since CentOS 7, not iptables.

Comment: This was an easy fix! Thanks for opening my eyes to the fact that `iptables` isn't enabled by default on CentOS 7. I just disabled `firewalld` with `sudo systemctl disable --now firewalld`, then installed and enabled `iptables-services` with `sudo yum -y install iptables-services && sudo systemctl enable --now iptables`. Afterward, everything worked as expected.